# What does "in-place" mean exactly?

Tags: algorithm, semantics, in-place

I know there are other questions about the meaning of the "in-place" algorithm but my question is a bit different. I know it means that the algorithm changes the original input data instead of allocating new space for the output. But what I'm not sure about is whether the auxiliary memory counts. Namely:

- if an algorithm allocates some additional memory in order to compute the result
- if an algorithm has a non-constant number of recursive calls which take up additional space on the stack

Comment: Where in god's name have I asked for any "book, tool etc..."?!

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I could see the question potentially being closed for another reason, but this makes no request for an off-site resource.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine question -- and definitely not a recommendation question -- but I can't vote to reopen it, sorry.  You might consider asking in chat.

Answer (score 2):

In-place normally implies sub-linear additional space.  This isn't necessarily part of the meaning of the term.  It's just that an in-place algorithm that uses linear or greater space is not  interesting.  If you're going to allocate O(n) space to compute an output in the same space as the input, you could have equally easily produced the output in fresh memory and maintained the same memory bound. The value of computing in-place has been lost.

Wikipedia goes farther and says [the amount of extra storage is constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).  However, an algorithm (say mergesort) that uses log(n) additional space to write the output over the input is still in-place in usages I have seen.

Comment: Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) page 148: "Recall that a sorting algorithm sorts in place if only a constant number of elements of the input array are ever stored outside the array."  But elsewhere it describes a recursive quicksort as in-place though it uses log n space for the stack.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom  Right. The Wikipedia article is equally confused and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any in-place algorithm that doesn't need *some* additional memory. Whether an algorithm is "in-place" is characterized by the following:

> **in-place**: To perform an algorithm on an input of size Θ(f(n)) using o(f(n)) extra space by mutating the input into the output.

Take for example an in-place implementation of the "Insertion Sort" sorting algorithm. The input is a list of numbers taking Θ(n) space. It takes Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) time to run in the worst case, but it only takes O(1) space.  If you were to not do the sort in-place, you would be *required* to use at least Ω(n) space, because the output needs to be a list of n numbers.